# Inject string into a href with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

In the same way that I can inject some text into a div with javascript, how can I inject a string into the href portion of an html anchor?

```
var div = document.getElementById('hrefId');
div.innerHTML = "Some dandy text!";
```

Something like this?

```
var hrefVar = document.getElementById('hrefId');
hrefVar.innerHTML = "Some dandy text!";
```

The problem is that it populates the space between `<a></a>`, as opposed to filling up the href with text, which is what I need to get the link to work.

```
<a href="" id="href"></a>
```

**Solution:**

```
var hrefVar = document.getElementById('hrefId');
hrefVar.href = "http://www.microsoft.com/";
```

Comment: `document.getElementById('whatever').href="some text"` or [`setAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) if you want to change the DOM and not just the element property

Comment: You should also be able to use Jquery, `$("#href").attr("href","Hello World");`

Comment: Why is the solution in the question?

Comment: Only the Universe truly knows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this was never ***officially*** answered I'll post it here.

Todo this with pure ***javascript***:

```
var hrefVar = document.getElementById('hrefId');
hrefVar.href = "http://www.microsoft.com/";
```

Or could do it in one line

```
var hrefVar = document.getElementById('hrefId').href="http://www.microsoft.com/";
```

***jQuery***:

```
$("#hrefId").attr("href","http://www.microsoft.com/");
```